# How do I download /dev/urandom?

Tags: curl, random, download, wget

Hello I need to download /dev/urandom for a project to disk. But:

```
wget /dev/random
/dev/random: Unsupported scheme.

curl file:///dev/urandom > testtt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

How do I do? I thought wget and curl would download it for me, I have unlimited disk space by my host so should not be a problem I thought. Thx.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do with /dev/urandom?

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/urandom` is not a real file. It's a special file that runs a kernel driver to generate random numbers on the fly. Since it has no length, a file transfer application wouldn't know when to stop reading from it, so it can't be copied or downloaded.